# Good PHP-based Stack Overflow clone?

Tags: discussion, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

I want to build a QA site like Stack Overflow (for a certain topic).
I already looked for good clones.

The best one I found was [Shapado](http://shapado.com/). This one requires Ruby and a few more modules.

Is there a PHP-based clone which is nearly as good as Shapado?

Comment: Here's a list of clones on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44637/open-source-php-clone-of-stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to check out [Coordino](http://www.coordino.com) it is a SO Clone built with CakePHP.

Comment: I looked at Coordino. Unfortunately its using CakePHP 1.3 and has some really bad practices baked in (like php short tags)

Answer (score 2):

You can also suggest your idea on [Area 51](http://www.area51.com).

Comment: A grand suggestion, sir!